# Android set layout weight in a BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I'm creating an app that simply displays some data in an ListView, this data should be added to the Listview using an Adapter.
In this adapter I'm trying to set the weight of an item in the list when its clicked.
I got the item to expand by setting the weight to 1 but when I'm trying to set the weight back to 0 nothing happens.

In this part of the code the first part where setting the layout weight to 1 does work but setting it back to 0 does not work.

```
 stat_item_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("HiscoreAdapter","Stat item height "+gained_tracker_container.getHeight());
            if(gained_tracker_container.getHeight() == 0){
                gained_tracker_container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
            }else{
                Log.w("HiscoreAdapter","Setting stat item weight to 0");
                gained_tracker_container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0));
            }
        }
    });
```

**The Adapter Class**

```html
public class HiscoreAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HiscoreItem> items;

    public HiscoreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HiscoreItem> items){
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_item, parent, false);

        final LinearLayout stat_item_container = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.stat_item_container);
        final LinearLayout gained_tracker_container = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.gained_tracker_container);
        TypedArray images = row.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.skill_icons);
        ImageView stats_icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.stats_icon);
        TextView rank_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rank_textview);
        TextView level_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.level_textview);
        TextView exp_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.exp_textview);
        TextView daily_levels_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.daily_levels_textview);
        TextView weekly_levels_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.weekly_levels_textview);
        TextView monthly_levels_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.monthly_levels_textview);
        TextView daily_exp_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.daily_exp_textview);
        TextView weekly_exp_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.weekly_exp_textview);
        TextView monthly_exp_textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.monthly_exp_textview);

        Picasso.with(row.getContext()).load("http://www.runescape.com/img/rsp777/hiscores/skill_icon_attack1.gif").into(stats_icon);
        //stats_icon.setBackgroundResource(images.getResourceId(position, defaultValue));
        rank_textview.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getRank()));
        level_textview.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getLevel()));
        exp_textview.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(position).getXp()));
        daily_levels_textview.setText("+"+String.valueOf(items.get(position).getDayLevelGains())+" lvl");
        weekly_levels_textview.setText("+"+String.valueOf(items.get(position).getWeekLevelGains())+" lvl");
        monthly_levels_textview.setText("+"+String.valueOf(items.get(position).getMonthLevelGains())+" lvl");
        daily_exp_textview.setText("+"+String.valueOf(items.get(position).getDayGains())+" exp");
        weekly_exp_textview.setText("+"+String.valueOf(items.get(position).getWeekGains())+" exp");
        monthly_exp_textview.setText("+"+String.valueOf(items.get(position).getMonthGains())+" exp");

        stat_item_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.w("HiscoreAdapter","Stat item height "+gained_tracker_container.getHeight());
                if(gained_tracker_container.getHeight() == 0){
                    gained_tracker_container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
                }else{
                    Log.w("HiscoreAdapter","Setting stat item weight to 0");
                    gained_tracker_container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0));
                }
            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to refresh the listview?

Comment: @AminMemariani you think that would solve it?

Comment: Yes I think so!

Comment: @AminMemariani well I do not want all the items to reload, is there a wat to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Try adapterObj.notifyDataSetChanged() after you alter your data

Comment: weight for items in ListViews is always wrap_content

Comment: @MoshErsan i do have it in wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayListObject.clear();
    ArrayListObject.addAll(DBClass.listAll(DBClass.class));
    AdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listViewObject.invalidateViews();
    listViewObject.refreshDrawableState();
```

Try this code to refresh your ListView. Add it before the return statement in your onItemClickedListener.

In second line I have used SugarORM to call my Data

Comment: You can see this code as an example: https://github.com/AminMemariani/BMICalculator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/aminmemariani/apps/bmicalculator/History.java